# How to send report parameters to .rdlc to display in header? (e.g. start and end dates)

Tags: asp.net, reportviewer

So, I have a ReportViewer control added to my ASP.NET 4.0 project which displays a report in local mode.  I use drop down boxes and text boxes to collect data from the user for use in the report (e.g. start date, end date).

How do I display this data in the header of the .rdlc report file, so that when people print out the report, they know what filters have been applied to the report (e.g. "Start Date: 1/1/2013, End Date: 1/1/2014")?

Answer (score 1):

This is a good tutorial on ReportParameters:
http://gotreportviewer.com/localmodeparameters/index.html

For every data collected you have to set parameter value and pass it to your report:

```
Dim parReportParam1 As New ReportParameter("parReportParam1", Me.TextBox1.Text)
Me.YourReportViewer.LocalReport.SetParameters(New ReportParameter() {parReportParam1})
```

In your report you have to add your parameter in design-mode and set textbox value as:

```
=Parameters!parReportParam1.Value
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: Hmm, I've tried this but the textbox in the report header in the .rdlc file that I assign the parameter to (=Paramters!myPar.Value) is always empty.  I have the above code in the _Click event for the button that refreshes the report.